# How to Return Last Selected Option in Dropdown List in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, drop-down-menu

So my question is simple. I want last option to be chosen/shown in dropdown menu depending on last selected option.

```
    {!! Form::select('number', ['1' => 'Koşuya Çıkmak', '2' => 'Yoga Yapmak' ]) !!}

   {!! Form::submit('Aktiviteyi Gerçekleştir!', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}

   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

So if user selected 2.value when this view opened I want option to be chosen already. Also other options should stay same in dropdown menu. How I can do it in a easiest way?

Comment: looks like `Form::select()` takes a third parameter that is the key of the selected item

Comment: So what do you suggest me to do in this case?

Comment: Any Suggestions??

Comment: {!! Form::select('number', ['1' => 'Koşuya Çıkmak', '2' => 'Yoga Yapmak' ], {{$value-selected}}) !!}  ---  that is the third parameter for the selected item

Comment: yeah i know it now but i have still problem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274631/is-it-possible-to-assign-variable-to-default-value-to-select-form-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment81510284_47274631