# Is it possible to assign variable to default value to select form in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel

So my question is, I have a form and I want this form to have default value and thats why I assigned $s variable. This variable comes from Controller, but It always gives error ;

**(2/2) ErrorException Undefined variable: s (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\X-GOTL\resources\views\actions\activity.blade.php)**

I know that this cant work because in the beginning there is no default value because its not sent by controller yet. I tried some ifs to fix it but anyways its not working. Also this $s value is equals to number of selected value in this form. Any ideas how I can fix this problem?

> {!! Form::select('number', ['1' => 'Koşuya Çıkmak', '2' => 'Yoga
>    Yapmak'], $s) !!}

This is code in controller.

```
    $activity = $request->number;

    $user_stat = Auth::user()->stat;
    $job_user = Auth::user()->stat;


    $userInfo = Auth::user();
    $id = $userInfo->id;
    $user = User::find($userInfo->id);


    if($activity == 1){

        $s = $request->number;


        $user_stat->str = Auth::user()->stat->str + 4;
        $user_stat->dex = Auth::user()->stat->dex + 4;

        $job_user->save();

        return redirect('/activity')->with('stat', '4 Güç ve 4 Beceri Kazandın!')->with(compact('s'));

    }
    elseif($activity == 2){

        $s = $request->number;

        $user_stat->str = Auth::user()->stat->str + 4;
        $user_stat->int = Auth::user()->stat->int + 4;

        $job_user->save();

        return redirect('/activity')->with('stat', '4 Güç ve 4 Zeka Kazandın!')
            ->with(compact('s'));

    }
```

Comment: {!! Form::select('number', ['1' => 'Koşuya Çıkmak', '2' => 'Yoga Yapmak'], isset($s) ? $s : "") !!}

Comment: now page works but its not returning a default value.

Comment: {!! Form::select('number', ['1' => 'Koşuya Çıkmak', '2' => 'Yoga Yapmak'], isset($s) ? $s : "DEFAULT VALUE") !!}

Comment: Are you passing `$s` to your view? Post your controller code.

Comment: yes I understand this like , but I want $s to become a default value, why Its still not working you think? ok let me post

Comment: Did i make some mistake about codes? What do you see guys?

Comment: @Berkeyalçın $s works fine while you are sending data from a controller. You are re-using the form that being said $s value needed each time.

Comment: So what i should do, i thought about creating other view to have this $s variable default value, should i try it again?

Comment: What I should do? What is solution?

Comment: I guess no need to create a different view. You can find more information here. http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field

Comment: yeah i checked it already, sad that i dont see or i cant understand any answer in that link :(

Comment: @Berkeyalçın Change your Controller code: `return redirect('/activity')->with('stat', 'xxx')->with('number', $request->number);` `{!! Form::select('number', ['1' => 'Koşuya Çıkmak', '2' => 'Yoga Yapmak'], isset($number) ? $number : 0) !!}` try this out. See it works or not.

Comment: Same its not working.. I cant understand why its not working...

Comment: Paste your full controller method. I suspect the "redirect with" might cause the problem. I guess you have to pass $s from the method returning the view in the first step, maybe with a default value and in the method responsible with the form processing pass it again. And this isn't looking ok: ->with('stat', 'xxx')->with(compact('s')); Why not ->with(['stat' => 'xxx', 's' => $s])?

Comment: I added example from controller, so you said why not with(['stat' => 'xxx', 's' => $s]), because Its not working and i think most proper is compact method. Because with 'stat' => 'xxx' i am sending session message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was so easy guys.. Just to add withInput()

> return redirect('/activity')->with('stat', 'xxx')->withInput();